# iptables rules choke off the connection or they leave wide open

Tags: linux, iptables

I've been working on enhancing my iptable rules. Here is abit of background on what I have done so far and what I'm planning on accomplishing and my issues:

I have an RPi and I have a WiFi module and have interfaced a 3G modem to it. I want to have all the traffic from my WiFi to be forwarded to my 3G interface. I created these rules and they work fine and I get full Internet access on the tablet when I pair up:

```
    echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
    iptables -t nat -F
    iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
    iptables -F
    iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu
    iptables -A FORWARD -i ppp0 -o wlan1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan1 -o ppp0 -j ACCEPT
```

Now I want to block that all up and only allow traffic going to two IP addresses to go through. I created a chain but things don't work as well as I had hoped:

```
    echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
    iptables -t nat -F
    iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
    iptables -F
    iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu
    iptables -N TEST
    iptables -A TEST -d 34.215.23.64 -j RETURN
    iptables -A TEST -d 52.37.29.39 -j RETURN
    iptables -A TEST -j ACCEPT 
    iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan1 -o ppp0 -j TEST
    iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan1 -o ppp0 -j DROP
```

When I execute this, all Internet access including to those two IP addresses get blocked off. I tried ! with the same outcome.

Can someone please help me figure out what I'm missing in this?

Thanks

Comment: Is there more to your rules?  I don't seen any drop/reject rules polices.  I am not sure why anything would get blocked.

Comment: Added one more rule that was a DROP: iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan1 -o ppp0 -j DROP. nothing else is there

Answer (score 0):

```
iptables -A TEST -d 34.215.23.64 -j RETURN
iptables -A TEST -d 52.37.29.39 -j RETURN
```

Your primary problem is that these rules are not going to be stateful, and you have only handled the rules in one direction.  If we pretend for a moment that there were no other problems, these rules would only handle the traffic in one direction.  But since you probably need bi-directional communication how are you going to get replies to anything you send that has a destination of '34.215.23.64'?  The reply will be a packet that as the source address of '34.215.23.64', and the destination would be your IP.

So you should consider at least adding back the (`iptables ... --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED ...`) rule.

```
iptables -N TEST
iptables -A TEST -d  -j RETURN
iptables -A TEST -d 34.215.23.64 -j RETURN
iptables -A TEST -d 52.37.29.39 -j RETURN
iptables -A TEST -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan1 -o ppp0 -j TEST
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan1 -o ppp0 -j DROP
```

But that isn't the only problem.  The logic of your chain is broken.

So a packet destined for `34.215.23.64` will first be processed on the forward.  It will first match the `-j TEST` rule.  On the TEST chain, that packet just is sent back to the chain (-j RETURN), and then the next matching rule is to DROP.

Anyway, try something like this instead.

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -F
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu
# permit all established connections
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
# chain for wlan -> ppp0 traffic
iptables -N WLAN2PPP
iptables -A WLAN2PPP -d 34.215.23.64 --state NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A WLAN2PPP -d 52.37.29.39 --state NEW -j ACCEPT
# everything else from wlan to ppp0 is dropped
iptables -A WLAN2PPP -j DROP
# send wlan1 -> ppp0 traffic to the chain. 
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan1 -o ppp0 -j WLAN2PPP
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks for the clear explanation! I just have a problem...iptables -A WLAN2PPP -d 34.215.23.64 --state NEW -j ACCEPT.... --state NEW produces an error and won't go through.